# Why does gcc -O3 handle avx256 compare intrinsic differently than gcc -O0 and clang?

Tags: c, gcc, simd, intrinsics, avx

I want to set two integer vectors and compare them with SIMD, and later on use this mask for a blend operation on packed floats. I produced the following code:

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(){
    __m256i is =  _mm256_setr_epi32(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
    __m256i js =  _mm256_set1_epi32(1);               // integer bit-patterns
    __m256 mask = _mm256_cmp_ps(is,js, _CMP_EQ_OQ);   // compare as subnormal floats

    float val[8];
    memcpy(val, &mask, sizeof(val));
    printf("%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f \n", val[0], val[1], val[2], val[3], val[4], val[5], val[6], val[7]);
}
```

which works fine with `gcc -mavx main.c` as well as `clang -mavx main.c` and `clang -O3 -mavx main.c`.

(Editor's note: it'll break with `-ffast-math` when cmpps treats those denormal inputs as `0.0` so all the compares are true.  You want AVX2 `_mm256_cmp_epi32` to do an *integer* compare, and `_mm256_castsi256_ps` the result.  But that's unrelated to the question about `gcc -O0` and clang allowing implicit conversion from `__m256i` to `__m256`)

However, when I use `gcc -O3 -mavx main.c` I get the following error message:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:9:33: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘_mm256_cmp_ps’
    9 |     __m256 mask = _mm256_cmp_ps(is,js, _CMP_EQ_OQ);
      |                                 ^~
      |                                 |
      |                                 __m256i {aka __vector(4) long long int}
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.3.0/include/immintrin.h:51,
                 from main.c:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.3.0/include/avxintrin.h:404:23: note: expected ‘__m256’ {aka ‘__vector(8) float’} but argument is of type ‘__m256i’ {aka ‘__vector(4) long long int’}
  404 | _mm256_cmp_ps (__m256 __X, __m256 __Y, const int __P)
      |                ~~~~~~~^~~
main.c:9:36: error: incompatible type for argument 2 of ‘_mm256_cmp_ps’
    9 |     __m256 mask = _mm256_cmp_ps(is,js, _CMP_EQ_OQ);
      |                                    ^~
      |                                    |
      |                                    __m256i {aka __vector(4) long long int}
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.3.0/include/immintrin.h:51,
                 from main.c:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.3.0/include/avxintrin.h:404:35: note: expected ‘__m256’ {aka ‘__vector(8) float’} but argument is of type ‘__m256i’ {aka ‘__vector(4) long long int’}
  404 | _mm256_cmp_ps (__m256 __X, __m256 __Y, const int __P)
      |                            ~~~~~~~^~~
```

I notice two things. First of all, the compiler seems to treat `is` as `__m256i {aka __vector(4) long long int}` whereas it contains 8 ints. Secondly, the compiler is correct to complain, because the intel intrinsics guide [1](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) shows the arguments as `__m256`. I'm now confused why this code even worked at the beginning. And if it is indeed correct because the integers are casted to floats, then I don't understand why it doesn't work with `gcc -O3`.

I did not want to use `_mm256_cmpeq_epi32` which returns an `__m256i` and there (seems to be no) is no `blend_ps` instruction that accepts such a mask.

**Why do the compilers behave differently, and what is the *correct* way to do this operation?**

---

**Compiler versions**

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.3.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc/configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-pkgversion='Arch Linux 9.3.0-1' --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++,d --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --with-system-zlib --with-isl --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-clocale=gnu --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libssp --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-plugin --enable-install-libiberty --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-multilib --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp --enable-cet=auto gdc_include_dir=/usr/include/dlang/gdc
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.3.0 (Arch Linux 9.3.0-1)
```

```
$ clang -v
clang version 10.0.0 
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.3.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.3.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.3.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.3.0
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.3.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Candidate multilib: 32;@m32
Selected multilib: .;@m64
Found CUDA installation: /opt/cuda, version 10.1
```

[1] https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/

Comment: I edited the compiler compiler versions. In short: clang 10.0.0 and gcc 9.3.0

Comment: You do actually want `_mm256_cmpeq_epi32`, the missing ingredient is `_mm256_castsi256_ps` to cast that vector of 0 / -1 elements to `__m256` to keep the compiler happy about C types.  In asm, both types can live in YMM registers; the C type system might be more sensible if there was a 3rd type for "boolean" vectors from compare results, like Agner Fog does in his vectorclass C++ wrapper library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First of all, the compiler seems to treat `is` as `__m256i {aka __vector(4) long long int}` whereas it contains 8 ints.

The `__m128i` and larger similar vectors don't specify the actual size (and number) of integers stored in them. You can use the same `__m128i` type to store 16 `uint8_t`s or 2 `uint64_t`s or anything in between. The important part is that it is used to store integers. It is operations on `__m128i` and larger similar vectors what specifies the interpretation of the verctors as a pack of integers of a given width. For example, both `_mm_add_epi16` and `_mm_add_epi32` accept `__m128i` arguments, but the first one interprets it as a vector of 8 `uint16_t`s, and the second - 4 `uint32_t`s.

> Secondly, the compiler is correct to complain, because the intel intrinsics guide 1 shows the arguments as `__m256`.

I think, the compiler is correct to complain. That it compiles the code with `-O0` seems to be a compiler bug. In gcc, `__m128i` and other vectors are implemented using [`__attribute__((vector_size))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html) attributes, and the documentation says one should use `__builtin_convertvector` intrinsic to convert between vectors of different types.

The original definition of the `__m128i` and other vector types in Intel Software Developer's Manual, Section 3.1.1.10, doesn't say anything explicitly about convertibility of vectors of different types, though it does say this:

> These SIMD data types are not basic Standard C data types or C++ objects, so they may be used only with the assignment operator, passed as function arguments, and returned from a function call.

Given this, I gather that these vector types are not supposed to be implicitly convertible. You certainly cannot rely on that the conversion, if it does in fact compile, will have any particular behavior. That is especially given that integer vectors don't specify the size of their elements. Therefore, you should always use an intrinsic to define the type of conversion you want, e.g. `_mm_cvtepi32_ps`/`_mm_cvtepi32_pd` or `_mm_castsi128_ps`/`_mm_castsi128_pd`.

> I did not want to use `_mm256_cmpeq_epi32` which returns an `__m256i` and there (seems to be no) is no `blend_ps` instruction that accepts such a mask.

`_mm256_cmpeq_epi32` is AVX2, and there is `_mm256_blendv_epi8` in AVX2. If you're only limited to AVX then you have to operate on 128-bit integer vectors.

Using `_mm256_cmp_ps` to operate on integer vectors is incorrect because its behavior is different from integer comparison. In particular, there are special rules if at least one of the input operands matches a NaN bit pattern (e.g. with `_CMP_EQ_OQ` operand your comparison will always return `0` in the resulting vector element).

Comment: Thanks, that makes it clear to me that __m128i is a container and the interpretation is done by the different functions. I also switched the functions to `_mm256_cmpeq_epi32`, then I cast this with `_mm256_castsi256_ps` and now I can use the mask in `_mm256_blendv_ps` and it seems to work.

Comment: @lyinch Why not use `_mm256_blendv_epi8`? Note that passing result of an INT vector instruction to a FP vector instruction (or vise versa) may cause cross-domain performance penalty.

Comment: I want to blend two floating point vectors, based on the indices comparison, which is why I'm not using blend_epi8